# access struct of base class with a template varaible

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, struct, derived-class

I want to create a derived class of base class that has a template and to keep the template option

but I cannot access a struct that is part of the base class

here is an example:

```
template <typename T1>
class Base{
    public:
    Base(){}
    ~Base(){}

    struct Struct {
        int Integer=0;
    };

    virtual void Function(Struct NewStrcut){ }

    //void Proccess(int T_Var){
    void Proccess(T1 T_Var){
        // do something
    }

};

template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T>{
//class Derived : public Base{
    Derived(){}
    ~Derived(){}

    void Function(Struct NewStrcut){
        // do something
    }

};
```

I get the following error:

> error: ‘Struct’ has not been declared [build]    51 |     void
> Function(Struct NewStrcut){

I am using c++17 with GCC11 on Ubuntu18

Comment: `void Function(typename Base<T>::Struct NewStrcut){` at `Derived` maybe?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, Thanks but it doesn't work, 
I got the following error:
"error: ‘Base<T>::Struct’ is not a type"

Comment: @OrHirshfeld The proposed fix works just fine, as you can [see here](https://godbolt.org/z/Exeo6qdqG) (GCC11, c++17).

Comment: @Fareanor oh yes thanks, I missed that I need to add "typename"

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @πάνταῥεῖ @Fareanor I found an answer

just needed to add "typename Base::" before Struct

as you can see in the following code:

```
template <typename T1>
class Base{
    public:
    Base(){}
    ~Base(){}

    struct Struct {
        int Integer=0;
    };

    virtual void Function(Struct NewStrcut){ }

    //void Proccess(int T_Var){
    void Proccess(T1 T_Var){
        // do something
    }

};

template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T>{
//class Derived : public Base{
    Derived(){}
    ~Derived(){}

    void Function( typename Base<T>::Struct NewStrcut){
        // do something
    }

};
```